# presto - concat columns names

Tags: sql, presto

is it possible to concat columns names into an array?
for example, my table is:

```
key|name_changed|address_changed|number_changed
-----------------------------------------------
1  |true        |true           |false
```

I want to get:

```
key|changes
---------------------------------
1  |[name, address]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want an array:

```
select key,
       ((case when name_changed then array['name'] end) ||
        (case when address_changed then array['address'] end) ||
        (case when number_changed then array['number'] end)
       ) as changes
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4e63bd8e6248708b5dc28a7441f21c90) is a db<>fiddle using Postgres, which should be pretty similar to Presto with respect to handling arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want an array as the output, you can go about this in a couple of different ways.

One approach is to create an array with the labels for each column as element or `NULL` if the element is false. This is achieved by the expression `if(name_changed, 'name')`, which are a short-hand for `CASE WHEN condition THEN if_true END`. Note that it returns `NULL` if the condition is false. To remove the nulls from the resulting array, use the [`filter`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#filter) function with a [lambda expression](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/lambda.html) that excludes nulls: `e -> e is not null`.

```sql
WITH data(key, name_changed, address_changed, number_changed)
AS (values (1, true, true, false))
SELECT 
    key,
    filter(
        array[if(name_changed, 'name'), if(address_changed, 'address'), if(number_changed, 'number')], 
        e -> e is not null) AS changes
FROM data
```

Another option that avoids using `filter` is to create an array for each label and then concatenate them all together. It's similar to the other answer above, but note that in Presto (and standard SQL), if any of the arguments to the [`||`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#concatenation-operator) operator is `NULL`, the result is `NULL`. To get around this, return an empty array from each of the [`if`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html#if) expressions if the condition is false:

```sql
WITH data(key, name_changed, address_changed, number_changed)
AS (values (1, true, true, false))
SELECT 
    key,
    if(name_changed, array['name'], array[]) || 
    if(address_changed, array['address'], array[]) || 
    if(number_changed, array['number'], array[]) AS changes
FROM data
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  key
            , concat(   case when name_changed = true then 'name' end, ', ',
                        case when address_changed = true then 'address' end, ', ', case when address_changed = true then 'address' end) as changes
```

Comment: While this may answer the OP's question, please provide an explanation for the answer.